# Is there a quicker way to carbonate a corny keg?

Tags: carbonation, corny-keg, kegs, kegging

Currently, if I want my beer "today" I put the gas into the out tube at the desired target pressure.  I then rest the keg on my lap and gently rock it for about 20 mins, until I don't hear any more bubbling.  Then I let it sit for a few hours.

Is there an easier way to carbonate quickly?  I hate having to disconnect my gas line to get the keg out of the fridge, and I hate sitting on the floor treating a corny keg like a baby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, do make sure the beer is cold before doing your pressurize and shake. The colder the liquid, the more CO2 it can absorb. Otherwise, you can't go much faster than you mention as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

That's about the fastest method I know of.

But, I've stopped doing it. It might just be me, but I've found I prefer a slightly slower approach. I'll turn up the pressure for 2-3 days and let it sit in the fridge until at the right pressure.

It might not make much of a difference, but the carbonation feels different in my mouth.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that carbonating through a tube that's submerged in the beer is faster, for example through the dip tube, by attaching the CO2 to the out line, or using a special [carbonating keg lid](http://morebeer.com/view_product/18212/).

You could also make your own DIY carbonating lid.

I've heard this method can cut the time in half or better.

I've never tried this though, so I can't vouch for it's efficacy. I've heard it has pros and cons.